# Django, how can I show variables in other model class?

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I'm learning Django and I'm trying to understand its logic. There are 2 models I created. I am designing a job listing page. The first model is "Business". I publish the classes inside this model in my html page and for loop. {% job %} {% endfor %}. But inside my second model in this loop I want to show company_logo class inside "Company" model but I am failing.
Methods I tried to learn;
1- I created a second loop inside the job loop, company loop, and published it failed.
2- I assigned a variable named company_list to the Job class on the views page and made it equal to = Company.objects.all() but it still fails.

**Here are my codes.**

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from ckeditor.fields import RichTextField
from djmoney.models.fields import MoneyField


JobTypes = (
    ('Full-Time', 'Full-Time'), ('Part-Time', 'Part-Time'), 
    ('Internship', 'Internship'),  ('Temporary', 'Temporary'), ('Government', 'Government')
    )

class Job(models.Model):

    job_title = models.CharField( max_length=100,  null=True)
    job_description = RichTextField()
    job_application_url = models.URLField(unique=True)
    job_type = models.CharField(max_length=15, choices=JobTypes, default='Full-Time')
    #job_category
    job_location = models.CharField( max_length=100)
    job_salary = MoneyField(max_digits=14, decimal_places=4, default_currency='USD')
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    featured_listing = models.BooleanField( default=False)

    company = models.ForeignKey(
        "Company", on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.company}: {self.job_title}"
    


class Company(models.Model):
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    company_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)
    company_url = models.URLField(unique=True)
    company_logo = models.ImageField(
        upload_to='company_logos/')
    
    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.company_name}"
```

views.py

```
from django.utils import timezone
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import Company, Job

def index(request):
    jobs = Job.objects.all().order_by('-created_date')[:3]
    company_list  = Company.objects.all()
    context = {
        'jobs': jobs,
        'company_list':company_list,
    }
    return render(request, 'index.html', context)
```

*"{% static 'company.company_logo.url' %}" on this page this code is not working.* *For example, in the coming days I will create a user model and I will have this problem again while publishing the "user.user_name" variable, which will be an example, in my html page. What is the logic here?*
**index.html**

```
{% extends '_base.html' %}
{% load static %}
{% block content %}
<div class="container">
    <!-- Recent Jobs -->
    <div class="eleven columns">
    <div class="padding-right">
        <h3 class="margin-bottom-25">Recent Jobs</h3>
        <ul class="job-list">
        {% for job in jobs %}
            <li class="highlighted"><a href="job-page.html">
                <img src="{{ job.company.company_logo.url}}" alt="Logo" class="company-logo">
                <div class="job-list-content">
                    <h4>{{ job.job_title }} <span class="full-time">{{ job.job_type }}</span></h4>
                    <div class="job-icons">
                        <span><i class="fa fa-briefcase"></i>{{ job.company }}</span>
                        <span><i class="fa fa-map-marker"></i> {{ job.job_location }}</span>
                        {% if job.job_salary %}
                        <span><i class="fa fa-money"></i> {{job.job_salary}}</span>
                        {% else %}
                        <span><i class="fa fa-money"></i>Salary undisclosed</span>
                        {% endif %}
                    </div>
                </div>
                </a>
                <div class="clearfix"></div>
            </li>
    {% endfor %}
        </ul>

        <a href="browse-jobs.html" class="button centered"><i class="fa fa-plus-circle"></i> Show More Jobs</a>
        <div class="margin-bottom-55"></div>
    </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Job Spotlight -->
  <div class="five columns">
        <h3 class="margin-bottom-5">Featured</h3>

        <!-- Navigation -->
        <div class="showbiz-navigation">
            <div id="showbiz_left_1" class="sb-navigation-left"><i class="fa fa-angle-left"></i></div>
            <div id="showbiz_right_1" class="sb-navigation-right"><i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i></div>
        </div>
        <div class="clearfix"></div>
        
        <!-- Showbiz Container -->
        <div id="job-spotlight" class="showbiz-container">
            <div class="showbiz" data-left="#showbiz_left_1" data-right="#showbiz_right_1" data-play="#showbiz_play_1" >
                <div class="overflowholder">

                    <ul>
            {% for job in jobs %}
            {% if job.featured_listing %}
                        <li>
                            <div class="job-spotlight">
                                <a href="#"><h4>{{job.job_title}} <span class="freelance">{{job.job_type}}</span></h4></a>
                                <span><i class="fa fa-briefcase"></i>{{job.company}}</span>
                                <span><i class="fa fa-map-marker"></i> {{job.job_location}}</span>
                                <span><i class="fa fa-money"></i> {{job.job_salary}} / hour</span>
                                <p>{{ job.job_description | safe | truncatechars:150  }}</p>
                                <a href="job-page.html" class="button">Apply For This Job</a>
                            </div>
                        </li>
            {% endif %}
            {% endfor %}
                    </ul>
                    <div class="clearfix"></div>

                </div>
                <div class="clearfix"></div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

index.html problem: [image]

urls.py

from django.urls import path
from . import views
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.conf import settings

```
from django.urls import path 
from . import views 
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.conf import settings


urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index,name="index"),
    #path("jobs/", JobListView.as_view(), name="jobs")
]
urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

Answer (score 0):

the syntax is not

```
{% static 'company.company_logo.url' %} or **{% static 'company.company_logo.url' %}**
```

use this instead

```
{{ company.company_logo.url }}
```

also if you want to make relations between Job and Company, you can make it like so

inside **Job** model add this new field

```
company = models.ForeignKey('Company', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

So that one company can have multiple jobs

Then inside the **job for loop** in HTML just add this to display company_logo

```
{% for job in jobs %}

    *..........remaining code..........*

    <img src="{{ job.company.company_logo.url }}" alt="">

    *..........remaining code..........*

{% endfor %}
```

Comment: {{ company.company_logo.url }}
I edited this code. but still the logo is not showing.  and model there is already a field named company.  When I examine the codes in the chrome browser, the logo works but does not appear in the html page.

Comment: I tried this code in a blank area and all logos came out.

{% for x in company_list %}
<img src="{{ x.company_logo.url}}" alt="">
{% endfor %}
{% endblock content %}

I changed the first for loop I shared with this to show the logo, still it didn't show up. There may be problems with images in general. It's a simple bug but I couldn't find it. I've been dealing with this until tonight.

Comment: have you added this inside **urls.py**

`from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)`

Comment: Also in your **index.html** I didn't see forloop for company_list

Comment: I re-edited the codes and added a screenshot of the problem. but the problem still persists. I couldn't understand how to create for company_list in index.html file. For example, I created a for like this; {% for x in company_list %}
<img src="{{ x.company_logo.url}}" alt="">
{% endfor%}

but still logos are not showing and trying to show all logos.